# How to replace line in file with pattern with sed?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, sed

I'm reading a lot of documentation on sed, and am still stumped on my particular use case.

I want to replace this line in a conf file with my own line:

Replace this line:

```
#maxmemory <bytes>
```

with:

```
maxmemory 26gb
```

This is what I tried:

```
sed s/maxmemory.*bytes.*/maxmemory 26gb/ /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command
```

Which stumps me because I don't know what that means. So my question is:

How can I accomplish what I want?
What does that error mean? (so I can learn from it)

Answer (score 38):

You have forgot -i. Modification should be made in place :

`$ sed -i 's/maxmemory.*/maxmemory 26gb/' /some/file/some/where.txt`

Comment: And if you have slashes in your strings, you must use another delimiter character instead of `/`, such as `@` or `|`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366940/4561887 and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259087/114401.

Comment: Concise and precisely what one will typically need.
Thanks a lot, @Phantom.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed

The error means that in the absence of quotes, your shell uses spaces to separate arguments. The space between `maxmemory` and `26gb` is thus considered as terminating the first argument, which thus lacks a terminal `/` when `sed` comes to parse that argument as one of its commands.

Putting your regex between single quotes, so that your shell doesn't split it into multiple arguments and hands it to `sed` as one single argument, solves the problem:

```
$ sed s/maxmemory.*/maxmemory 26gb/ /some/file/some/where.txt
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 23: commande `s' inachevée
```

while

```
$ sed 's/maxmemory.*/maxmemory 26gb/' /some/file/some/where.txt
```

works.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not `sed` that does this.  It's the _shell_ that does this.

Comment: you're right, of course, thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3):

Your use case will be solved by this command.

```
sed -i -e 's/#maxmemory.*/maxmemory 26gb/g' /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add a small explanation.

Comment: -e was needed for MacOS in my case