# Command to disable password login via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, login, sshd

So,
I am aware I can disable password authentication via ssh by modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by changing `PasswordAuthentication Yes` to `PasswordAuthentication no`. I want to ensure ssh logins can only be done via a keyfile for every user.

Is there a nice one-liner command that sets this option?

Comment: SED? https://superuser.com/questions/723441/how-to-replace-line-in-file-with-pattern-with-sed https://superuser.com/questions/618407/multiple-search-and-replace-actions-in-one-large-text-file

Comment: Do you want a command to change a single value in the configuration file, is that it? Is that for just one server?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I just want to change this one value from Yes to No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I successfully tested this:

```
sudo sed -E -i 's|^#?(PasswordAuthentication)\s.*|\1 no|' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
if ! grep '^PasswordAuthentication\s' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; then echo 'PasswordAuthentication no' |sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config; fi
```

This will use `sed` to edit the file in-place. In addition to replacing whatever follows `PasswordAuthentication` with `no`, it will remove the comment at the beginning of the line, which is there by default on Ubuntu. If this command is run a 2nd or 3rd time, there will be no additional change to the file.

The second line adds the config option to the file in case it was deleted somehow.